# Python - How to specify an order in fnmatch()?

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

I am trying to create `for` loop in Python, using `fnmatch` to catch all desired files in directory. Due to further merging of files, I would require to run this loop based on file names (e.g. run file 20180301 through code before 20180302 etc.).

Currently I simply use the following line to get files:

```
for file_name in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(source_dir), "Test_" + instance + "_*.csv"):
```

Is it possible to create some sort of sorting within `fnmatch`? I found some options to do that with `glob`, but would prefer to stick with `fnmatch` if possible (as otherwise there will be quite some changes required within code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this:

```
for file_name in sorted(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(source_dir), "Test_" + instance + "_*.csv")):
```

Comment: That did the trick, cheers for fast response and help! I did not know sorted can be used in fnmatch as well, still getting the grip of python.